# MapBox iOS: how to vary pitch depending on the zoom level?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am using MapBox SDK for iOS, and I would like to set a different pitch level depending on the zoom level, like for example in Pokemon Go: the more the view is zoomed out and the more it's aerial, and when it's zoomed in the pitch increases, at a point that we can see the sky above the horizon.

Is there a way to do so with that SDK?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox has two delegate functions (https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/4.2.0/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/MGLMapViewDelegate) that you can use:

`optional func mapViewRegionIsChanging(_ mapView: MGLMapView)`

`optional func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)`

These get called whenever the currently displayed map camera is changing or has finished changing and so check zoom level within them and adjust pitch accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! The first delegate function was the key.